# x86 inline assembler flag

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

Silly question, but I just can not find the necessary flag in gcc. Basically, I have in my C program the following inline assembler code

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("lea ebx, [timings] \n\t");
```

When compiling, I get an errormessage which says: `Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2`[timings]'`

Now I remember that a long time ago I used some kind of flag that told the compiler that it is x86 inline assembly. But cant find it online, could maybe someone please tell me which flag i have to use?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

You can't specify variables that way with GCC.  See [this document](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) for a detailed description of how to use inline assembler.  Also, keep in mind that GCC uses AT&T syntax, not Intel syntax, so you have to put your destinations on the right.

Comment: I did it in the past, you can specify with the compiler that you use intel syntax but silly me has forgotten how to to that

Comment: I don't know how well it works, but from the GCC documentation: `-masm=DIALECT' Output asm instructions using selected DIALECT.  Supported choices are `intel' or `att' (the default one).  Darwin does not support `intel'.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `__asm__` instead. Look [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s4) for more.

Also, try removing the \n\t from inside the assembly code.